# Undefined index when making post request

Tags: objective-c, postman

I have a post request, I'm sending a body in that request, I tried it on postman and it worked well as shown in the image posted, I took the code from the postman, as shown in the next image, and pasted it in my xcode project, the full code below:

```
 NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
                               @"x-session": @"48afbfc4c633983555caa8a816a00e966fb22863",
                               @"cache-control": @"no-cache",
                               @"postman-token": @"5a2ba3be-42e0-95e3-2866-29f8ce83c32a" };
    NSArray *parameters = @[ @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][company_name]", @"value": @"Ali" },
                             @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][type_id]", @"value": @"5" },
                             @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][contact_fname]", @"value": @"jaber" },
                             @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][contact_lname]", @"value": @"jaber2" },
                             @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][contact_phone]", @"value": @"70034491" },
                             @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][remark]", @"value": @"sdsdd" },
                             @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][images][0]", @"value": @"https://otrackapi.omegasoftware.ca/ActStaff/public/uploads/user-image-94.jpg" },
                             @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][lat]", @"value": @"33.311" },
                             @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][lng]", @"value": @"33.234" },
                             @{ @"name": @"contacts[0][contact_email]", @"value": @"me@me.com" } ];
    NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";

    NSError *error;
    NSMutableString *body = [NSMutableString string];
    for (NSDictionary *param in parameters) {
        [body appendFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary];
        if (param[@"fileName"]) {
            [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", param[@"name"], param[@"fileName"]];
            [body appendFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n", param[@"contentType"]];
            [body appendFormat:@"%@", [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:param[@"fileName"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]];
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error);
            }
        } else {
            [body appendFormat:@"Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param[@"name"]];
            [body appendFormat:@"%@", param[@"value"]];
        }
    }
    [body appendFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary];
    NSData *postData = [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
                                                           cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                       timeoutInterval:10.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                                completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                    if (error) {
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                    } else {
                                                        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
                                                        NSLog(@"%@", httpResponse);
                                                    }
                                                }];
    [dataTask resume];
```

the response is returning the following error :

```
response =     {
        exception = GeneralException;
        message = "Undefined index: type_id";
    };
```

after I asked the backend guys, this error means that the type_id is not included.
but actually it is included, and I didn't change the code gotten from postman.
Anyone could have an idea whats going around?

Thanks

[image: postman code]
[image: postman success request]

Answer (score 0):

I think this error is because you pass 5 like a string in the dictionary, pass it like a number, with `@(5)`.